# Find the extreme values of an absolute function on a given interval

Tags: calculus, absolute-value, extreme-value-theorem

(Q) Find the extreme values for $f(x)=|3x-5|$ on $-3≤x≤2$

Because this is an absolute function $f'(x)=0$ does not exist.

There is a local minimum at $x=\frac{5}{3}$

For the interval $-3≤x≤2$, $$f(-3)=14$$ $$f(2)=1$$

Thus, the extreme values are local maximum at $(-3,14)$ and local minimum at $(\frac{5}{3}, 0)$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes. Since you have a function of the form $f(x) = |ax+b|$, you know $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. Thus, the minimum would occur wherever $f(x) = 0$, on the premise it's in the interval -- and checking it, you indeed determine that is the case. Moreover, you know that minimum will be unique, and thus any maxima will occur at other $x$ values. Since $f'(x) = \pm a$ (the sign depending on which side of the minimum you're on), you can also immediately see that such an $f$ will have maxima at the endpoints of the interval, and thus checking them is sufficient to find them: just take the greater of the two.

You can also verify your answer by graphing your function $f$ in Desmos or other software, if you please:

[image]